# Commutation relations for angular momentum operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, notation, commutator

I was reading Sakurai's Quantum Mechanics and I'm having some trouble with the following computation:
I need to verify that:
$$[  S_i, S_j] = i \hbar \epsilon_{ijk}S_k , i \in \{1,2,3\}$$
For $i = 1,y = 2$ I obtained:
$$ [S_1,S_2] = S_1S_2 -S_2S_1 = \frac{\hbar^2}{4} (\sigma_1 \sigma_2 - \sigma_2 \sigma_1 )= \cdots  = {i\over 2} \hbar^2 \sigma_3  = i\hbar S_3 $$
But when I try to use the direct formula I get:
$$\text{For } k = 3: \epsilon_{ij3}S_3 = S_3(\epsilon_{123} + \epsilon_{213}) = S_3(1-1) = 0 \Rightarrow [S_1,S_2] = 0$$
I know this is a stupid question, but I've never encountered the levi-civita symbols, therefore I'm not totally sure what I did is correct. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The left hands side commutator is antisymmetric in 1&2, but in your last line you wrote a symmetric expression. Flip the relative sign.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to: I computed every term of $\epsilon_{ij3}$ and I was left those two terms only. I can't see  the extra minus sign you mentioned. Could you explain further

Comment: And thanks for the edit

Comment: The interchange symmetries/antisymmetries of the l.h.side must match that of the right-hand side, so the rhside must also be antisymmetric in 1&2. You simply blew the relative sign of the two terms you wrote. The εs reinforce, instead of cancelling.

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing it out. This fact is not specified anywhere in the book unfortunately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the general formula

$$[S_i, S_j] = i\hbar\epsilon_{ijk}S_k$$

$i$ and $j$ are $\textit{free indices}$ - they can take any value in $\{1,2,3\}$, but are fixed once they assume a specific value. $k$ is an index which is summed over. For $i=1$ and $j=2$, the expression reads

$$\begin{align}
[S_1,S_2] &= i\hbar\,\epsilon_{12k}S_k \\
&= i\hbar(\epsilon_{121}S_1+ \epsilon_{122}S_2+ \epsilon_{123}S_3) \\
&=i\hbar\,S_3 \\
\end{align}$$

The last line follows from the definition of $\epsilon_{ijk}$.